# Erro ao chamar o route debugger

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nuget

Instalei o Route Debugger via NuGet: **Install-Package WebApiRouteDebugger**. Quando rodo a minha aplicação, e chamo o debugger de rota(**http://localhost:9078/rd**), dessa forma, explode esse erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas a referência **System.Web.Optimization** está adicionada no projeto e não tem conflito algum. Como eu resolvo isso? Isso aconteceu após a instalação do package

Comment: O seu web.config esta com a mesma versão que o assembly?

Comment: @GabrielColetta, estava funcionando. Aconteceu após eu ter instalado o package para debugar as rotas, para resolver outro problema. Desinstalei a DLL e também a webgrease, funcionou. Acho que foram instaladas no package e desinstalei o package e esquece o debug de rotas.

Comment: O que acontece é que o WebApiRouteDebugger precisa de algumas dependências com certas versões, se você já usava essas dependências, é bem provável que ele atualizou para evitar conflito e não atualizou a versão especificada no seu web.config.

Comment: @GabrielColetta, entendi. Seria uma ótima ajuda para desenvolver. Vou deixar para mais tarde, pois preciso fazer o meu método com parâmetro funcionar no meu webapi e não está.